# Can I use a loop in R to generate additional R code?

Tags: r

I would like to do a loop that will generate additional code but do not know how to do this.

```
i = 1
while (i <= 6) { (some code here)
i=i+1
}
```

The output would be to create the following new lines of R code in the dame or a new chunk

```
df1 <- load10X(This path would come from another data frame)
df2 <- load10X(This path would come from another data frame)
df3 <- load10X(This path would come from another data frame)
df4 <- load10X(This path would come from another data frame)
df5 <- load10X(This path would come from another data frame)
df6 <- load10X(This path would come from another data frame)
```

Any help would be appreciated
Dan

Comment: Use lists not many separate objects. As this [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451) advises: *Don't ever create `d1` `d2` `d3`, ..., `dn` in the first place. Create a list `d` with `n` elements.*

Comment: Specifically for you, `dfs <- lapply(mylistofdfs, load10X)`, `dfs[[1]]` for 1st item, `dfs[[2]]` for  2nd item, ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Parfait. Here is the code I would use for this:

```
temp = paste('/path to folder',list.files(path='path to folder'),sep='')
             
myfiles = lapply(temp, load10X)
```